# ¿por qué no muestra la vista previa al crear nuevo layout?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Hola hasta el momento no había tenido ningún problema al generar layouts con Android Studio. No obstante acabo de crear un proyecto nuevo y al generar un nuevo layout no muestra la vista previa y simplemente muestra un rectángulo negro.

Ya intente cambiar la configuración del gradle, limpiar el proyecto y volverlo a compilar, eliminar la cache y nada me ha funcionado.
Aquí les dejo unas imágenes de mi gradle y de la vista previa.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jefteapps.barbeuser"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "alpha 0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
}
```

Así es como se muestra la vista previa del layout:

[image: así es como se muestra la vista previa del proyecto:]
Finalmente esta es la advertencia que muestra, que no entiendo muy bien a que se refiere:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@774fbf09
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor470.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)
    at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawableStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:7101)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.drawableStateChanged(AppBarLayout.java:393)
    at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```